# create a service to return my external ip

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi is there any way to create my own page in my web server so that i can ping it from external application to get the WAN ip from where the application is hosted? Something like whatismyip but on my own server.

Answer (score 0):

What about next code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1
{
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender,
    EventArgs e)
{
    // Get request.
    HttpRequest request = base.Request;

    // Get UserHostAddress property.
    string address = request.UserHostAddress;

    // Write to response.
    base.Response.Write(address);

    // Done.
    base.CompleteRequest();
}
}
}
```